# Can't understand nextProps in shouldComponentUpdate()?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

In method "shouldComponentUpdate()" (in App component), the state of Button click is updated, everything is re-rendered and the updated state is only passed as props to Lifecycle component. How this.props.text in the Lifecycle component refers to the previous state's value?

````
  class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      text : "hello_"
    }
  }


  handle = () =>{
    this.setState({text : this.state.text+'hello_'})
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>
        {'App' + this.state.text}
        </p>
        <button onClick = {this.handle}> click </button>
        <Lifecycle text = {this.state.text}/>
      </div>
      )
  }
}


Lifecycle.js
  class Lifecycle extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }

 
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate', nextProps, this.props.text)
    return true
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
         {this.props.text}
        </div>
      )
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` lets you customize the way props and state are compared (your own function or a 3rd party library). Current props and state will be compared and a bool value returned.

Comment: first of all thatks for answering, oh okay! after updating the state only  we 're passing the updated state as props to child component  then how come this.props in the child component refers to the previous state?

Comment: I don't think about it as "previous state" and "next state", but rather "current state" and "next state". When `setState` is called a new render tree will be built and compared to the current one. When you use `Component` as a child, it will always re-render when its parent does. `ShouldComponentUpdate` lets you write your own logic "current state vs upcoming / next state" and based on that logic - whether the child should update (re-render). Inside your component you always have access to the current state and props, while `ShouldComponentUpdate` will receive the "next ones".